# Vue Multiple if condition inside for loop blade laravel

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

So I had this condition in my blade template in laravel, all the items value are obtained from method calculated using vue, the problem is I want to change the value based on condition and it has 3 condition, This is my code :

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
                        <td>@{{ item.nama }}</td>
                        <td>@{{ item.ndaftar }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <template v-if="item.status === 99">
                                <img src='{{ asset("images/standby.jpg") }}'>
                            </template>
                            <template v-else-if="item.status = 0">
                                <img src='{{ asset("images/failed.jpg") }}'>
                            </template>
                            <template v-else>
                                <img src='{{ asset("images/success.jpg") }}'>
                            </template>
                        </td>
</tr>
```

And below is my method in antrian.js

```
getVueItems: function (page) {
            this.$http.get('/antrianitems?page=' + page).then((response) => {
                this.$set('items', response.data.data.data);
                this.$set('pagination', response.data.pagination);
            });
        },
```

In Laravel is really simple just using if and chain it even inside for loop, but I doesnt work like that in vue, and template even only support for if and else, no else-if.

How do I achieve in blade template using vue :

if @{{ item.status }} = 99 then show image standby,
if @{{ item.status }} = 0 then show image failed,
else then show image success,

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue does indeed support [else-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else-if), although only since 2.1.0, maybe you just need a more recent version.

Your code should technically work, although you have some syntactic issues (in line 8, you should use do a compare instead of an assignment and there seems to be a leftover `--}}`).

But a cleaner way to do it would be to write a method in your component:

```
methods: {
  getItemImage: function(status) {
    if (status === 99) {
      return 'Standby';
    } else if (status === 0) {
      return 'Failed';
    } else {
      return 'Success';
    }
  }
}
```

Your template can then be reduced to:

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
  <td>@{{ item.nama }}</td>
  <td>@{{ item.ndaftar }}</td>
  <td>
    <img :src="getItemImage(item.status) + '.jpg'" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It works show the image name in source code. but my image are in {{ asset('images/img.jpg') }}

and it's not showing, I already put {{ asset() }} inside getItemImage method but it just wont work.. any  solution?

Comment: nevermind I just put "return "/images/succesfailedorstandby.png" and everything done... Thanks.